# Проверить количество стобцов в строке CSV-файла

Tags: java

Необходимо узнать, сколько стобцов(С помощью разделителя) в строке CSV-файла,при более n-стобцов, строку пропускаем, но при этом строка может быть огромной, из-за чего система может зависнуть. Как мне определить сколько стобцов, не считывая строку из файла в программу?

Comment: поидее никак. Только надо считать строку.

Comment: @Chubatiy Решил посимвольно считывать и каждый раз, когда встречаю разделитель, увеличивать счётчик, когда счётчик достигает определенного значения, кидаю ошибку.

Comment: Вариант. Но как вы узнаете, что строка закончилась? И надо читать следующую? Вам же надо просто пропустить, а не выкинуть ошибку(судя по ТЗ)

Comment: @Chubatiy проверяю на '/n'

Comment: верно, но для этого вам же надо прочитать её до конца. То есть вы всё равно вычитываете всю строку, просто по 1 символу?

Comment: @Chubatiy Извиняюсь, ТЗ изменилось, сказали, что просто кидать ошибку.

Comment: А. Тогда ясно. Спасибо за разъяснение